# Activation key change

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software, change-script

How do I change the activation key from scroll wheel to scrolllock?

```
local Macro_Activation_Key = 3
local function OutputLogs(s)
   OutputLogMessage(s.."\n")
   OutputDebugMessage(s.."\n")
end 
local Recoil_Activator
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == Macro_Activation_Key then
        Recoil_Activator = not Recoil_Activator 
        OutputLogs(Recoil_Activator and "ON_Macro" or "OFF_Macro")
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and Recoil_Activator then 
        MoveMouseRelative(2, -2)
        repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(-4, 4)
        Sleep(3)
        MoveMouseRelative(4, -4)
        Sleep(3)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Please do not add any dummy text to your question.

Comment: @Progman - This was probably done due to SO limitation on the minimal text size required to post a beginners' question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use function `IsKeyLockOn`

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then 
        MoveMouseRelative(2, -2)
        repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(-4, 4)
            Sleep(3)
            MoveMouseRelative(4, -4)
            Sleep(3)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
end
```